# problems in removing white space within text nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Am having some issues removing white space within the text nodes. this are the codes i used but still the spaces wouldn't go.

```
 <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/> 
 <xsl:template match="/">

    <Address>  <xsl:apply-templates/> </Address>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Address/Rowinfo ">

     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="LocatorDesignator"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="LocatorName"/>

    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="Address/Rowinfo/LocatorDesignator">

    <xsl:value-of select = "normalize-space(LocatorDesignator)"/> 
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Address/Rowinfo/LocatorName">

    <xsl:value-of select = "normalize-space(LocatorName)"/> 
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

it produces the same result. this is a sample xml data with whites space within its text node.

```
<Address>
<Rowinfo>
<Locator>mr oga,    Ade  </Locator>
<LocatorDesignator>Dwelling(Part Of),   Null </LocatorDesignator>
</Rowinfo>
```

my intended output is

```
   <Locator>mr oga, Ade</Locator>
  <LocatorDesignator>Dwelling(Part Of),Null</LocatorDesignator>
```

Comment: you could also just use translate(value,' ','') if you want all of the spaces removed

Comment: lee, what is "it"? What is the wanted result? Could you, please edit the question and provide only short XML document and the exact wanted result? Given the title of the question, I would expect a document like: `<text>  Good     Morning   . </text>` and wanted result for this XML document: `<p>Good Morning.</p>` This is a good way to ask a question -- all non-related details are removed.

Answer (score 2):

**A wellknown way of removing unwanted space from a text node** is to use the

**[normalize-space()](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space)**

function.

**Another complementary way of removing away white-space text nodes from the XML document** is the **[XSLT instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-strip-space)**:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

**A third way of removing text nodes that aren't matched by any other, more specific template** is by using the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

This is more powerful (and unwisely used can cause wanted text nodes to be "deleted" in the output).

People typically use a combination of the these three methods for removing unwanted white-space and text nodes.

Comment: @Dimitre.. am a newbie and some of your explanations are alittle complex for me at the moment try to illustrate with some sample code

Comment: @lee, You need to read a good book on XSLT/XPath. For now, just try using these techniques and see how they affect the processing of an XML document. I am going to my workplace in a few minutes, so it is impossible to extend the answer in this short time.

Answer (score 0):

Your templates are not used

instead of

```
<xsl:copy-of select="LocatorDesignator"/>
```

do

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="LocatorDesignator"/>
```

Or as JWiley suggested, remove the spaces with a [translate](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N7998.html)

```
<xsl:template match="Address/Rowinfo/LocatorDesignator">  
    <xsl:value-of select = "translate(.,' ', '')"/>  
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
</xsl:template>
```

Or as you have multiple ways to reach Rome:

```
 <xsl:copy-of select="translate(LocatorDesignator,' ','')"/>
```

Comment: am alittle confused can you produce a sample code? however does it get to strip all the spaces between the text? can you show me how the spaces are striped? probably am the one getting it wrong. am trying to get rid of the spaces so i can manipulate and delete unwanted text

Comment: I assume you can spot the lines where it says <xsl:copy-of ... and replace that with <xsl:apply-templates

Comment: still not producing the intended result

Comment: i tried it with you codes too, the spaces are still there             <p>Dwelling(Part Of),Null.......</p>